# ytdl-core Could not extract html5player key: https://www.youtube.com/s/player/6bc49f0e/player_ias.vflset/en_US/base.js

Tags: discord.js

Ok, so im having this problem where this keeps being posted in my console using ytdl-core @1.0.9`Could not extract html5player key: https://www.youtube.com/s/player/6bc49f0e/player_ias.vflset/en_US/base.js`

```js
function play(guild, song) {
  try{
    var serverQueue = queue.get(guild.id);

  if (!song) {
    queue.delete(guild.id);
    setTimeout(() => {
      serverQueue = queue.get(guild.id);
      if(!serverQueue){
        if(!guild.me.voiceChannel)return
        guild.me.voiceChannel.leave();
        return;
      }
      else{
        return;
      }
    }, 300000)
    return
  }
  const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection.playStream(ytdl(song.url, {filter: 'audioonly', highWaterMark: 1<<25 }))
        .on('end', reason => {
            if (reason === 'Stream is not generating quickly enough.') console.log('Song ended.');
      else console.log(reason);
      serverQueue.songs.shift();
      if(serverQueue.songs.length <= 0){
        serverQueue.volume = 1;
        SetGuildSavedVolume(guild.id, 1)
      }
            play(guild, serverQueue.songs[0]);
        })
    .on('error', error => console.error(error));
    let SavedQueueVolume = GetGuildSavedVolume(guild.id)
  dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(SavedQueueVolume / 3);
  DeleteGuildSongSkips(guild.id)
  serverQueue.textChannel.send({
    embed: {
      color: 3447003,
      author: {
        name: client.user.username,
        icon_url: client.user.avatarURL
      },
      title: "Playing music!",
      url: "http://google.com",
      description: "Now playing music! ",
        fields: [{
            name: "Song:",
            value: (song.title + "\n" + song.url)
          },],
      timestamp: new Date(),
      footer: {
        icon_url: client.user.avatarURL,
        text: "© Nexus music"
      }
    }
  });
}catch(err){
  console.log(err)
  let botlogschannel = client.channels.get("676874892850757642");
  let DevErrorEmbed =  new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setTitle("**An error has occurred! ❌**")
  .setDescription("**"+ err + "**\n\n" + err.stack)
  .setAuthor(client.user.username)
  .setColor(0xFF0000)
  .setTimestamp(new Date())
  return botlogschannel.send(DevErrorEmbed)
}
}
```

This is the code above, for the play function where the console.log(err) is placed and where the error is originating.I assume this is a bug within ytdl-core @1.0.9 since I have looked through similar reports of this and the author had said it was fixed, however i'm not completely certain so I hope someone here will know how to solve this issue.

Comment: Version 1.0.9 is outdated. Try updating to 2.0.1 (`npm i` should update all packages, or `npm i ytdl-core@2.0.1` will install it separately).